# Deserialize Json Object containing sub Array

Tags: c#, json

I have the following Json string (containing subArray):

> {"attributes":
>   [{"name":"a","data":["10","0","50"],"dataName":["2000248","2789290","2789291"],
>   "dataValue":["a","b","c"],"toClick":"d"},
>   {"name":"v","data":["0","0","0","20"]
>   ,"dataName":
>   ["49500000","49500001","49500002","49500003"],
>   "dataValue":["a","v","v","d"],"toClick":"d"}]}"

I can't deserialize in csharp.
[Updated after comment]
What I did:

```
public class attributes
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string[] data { get; set; }
    public string[] dataName { get; set; }
    public string[] dataValue { get; set; }
    public string toClick { get; set; }
}


public class DataJsonAttributeContainer
{
    public List<attributes> JsonAttributeAfterSaves { get; set; }
}

public static T DeserializeFromJson<T>(string json)
{
    T deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json, settings);
    return deserializedProduct;
}

private void testJson()
{
    string JsonStr =
        "{\"attributes\":[{\"name\":\"a\",\"data\":[\"10\",\"0\",\"50\"],\"dataName\":[\"2000248\",\"2789290\",\"2789291\"],\"dataValue\":[\"a\",\"a\",\"d\"],\"toClick\":\"d\"},{\"name\":\"d\",\"data\":[\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"20\"],\"dataName\":[\"49500000\",\"49500001\",\"49500002\",\"49500003\"],\"dataValue\":[\"a\",\"a\",\"d\",\"d\"],\"toClick\":\"a\"}]}";
    var container = DeserializeFromJson<DataJsonAttributeContainer>(JsonStr);
}
```

Test method:

```
testJson()
```

What can I do?

Comment: Why are you trying to deserialize the various properties to strings when they're arrays?

Comment: @JonSkeet but what I can do in order to get the property and the array?

Comment: @JohnJohnGa: Have you tried giving the properties appropriate types, e.g. `string[]` or `int[]`?

Comment: @JohnJohnGa: Please show a short but complete program with an attempt at the right types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your property within `DataJsonAttributeContainer` has the wrong name given your JSON. Here's an example which works as far as I can tell:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Attributes
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string[] data { get; set; }
    public string[] dataName { get; set; }
    public string[] dataValue { get; set; }
    public string toClick { get; set; }
}


public class DataJsonAttributeContainer
{
    public List<Attributes> attributes { get; set; }
}

class Test
{

    public static T DeserializeFromJson<T>(string json)
    {
        T deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
        return deserializedProduct;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        string JsonStr =
            "{\"attributes\":[{\"name\":\"a\",\"data\":[\"10\",\"0\",\"50\"],\"dataName\":[\"2000248\",\"2789290\",\"2789291\"],\"dataValue\":[\"a\",\"a\",\"d\"],\"toClick\":\"d\"},{\"name\":\"d\",\"data\":[\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"20\"],\"dataName\":[\"49500000\",\"49500001\",\"49500002\",\"49500003\"],\"dataValue\":[\"a\",\"a\",\"d\",\"d\"],\"toClick\":\"a\"}]}";
        var container = DeserializeFromJson<DataJsonAttributeContainer>(JsonStr);
        Console.WriteLine(container.attributes.Count); // Prints 2
        Console.WriteLine(container.attributes[0].data.Length); // Prints 3
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the correct types and, in the case of your `DataJsonAttributeContainer`, the correct property name too:

```
public class attributes
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int[] data { get; set; }
    public int[] dataName { get; set; }
    public string[] dataValue { get; set; }
    public string toClick { get; set; }
}

public class DataJsonAttributeContainer
{
    public List<attributes> attributes { get; set; }
}
```

With the previous definitions, the following works for me (after I removed the last `"` from your JSON string):

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataJsonAttributeContainer>(jsonString);
```